# Xcode 6: "Simulator in Use" error shows even though the simulator is NOT in use

Tags: ios, xcode6

With the new Xcode 6, sometimes when I switch between simulators - I receive the error message "Simulator in Use - The Simulator can't be launched because it's already in use".
However, the simulator is NOT in use - and I don't see it in the Activity Monitor either.
The only way to overcome this is to exit and reenter Xcode.

Has anyone found an easier way to overcome this annoying error?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have experienced similar thing.

I basically do what you do - exit and re-enter Xcode.

What I have discovered is that when you stop the simulator, don't run it / switch to another and run it so quickly.
Give a second or two before running would avoid the problem (in my case) 90%.

This is not the case only for Xcode 6, earlier versions had this problem, too, when one stops and runs very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue so many times this issue, you just close and reopen the `Xcode`. It will go for sure . Make sure no other `Xcode` should be running. If you have multiple Xcode then quit all of them.

Comment: I really wish there were a process we could just kill. It's such a pain to have to quit and reopen Xcode each time.

Comment: I wish the same, but it's worked for me in this way only.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. You don't need to close Xcode for that. I have explain every thing in details.

Follow this answer:

[Simulator in use - Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907950/simulator-in-use)